# .net list group by in java 8?

Tags: java, c#

I got a task that migrate code from C# to java 8.
And I have a problem with the C# codes below.

```
List<Log> lst = LogRepository.GetLogs(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);

return lst
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Title, x.ID })
.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.DataChangeTime).FirstOrDefault())
.ToList();
```

Yes ,the method GroupBy is easy,I know what is it doing.
But ,I can't figure out what is this series methods doing and what results will it return ? 
Finally,can anyone give me a java version solution ?

Comment: This `GroupBy` gets Title+Id-groups, those groups are internally ordered so that the latest DataChangeTime-log is returned for each group. These latest logs are added to a list. Btw, replace `FirstOrDefault` with `First`, it's not possible that a group is empty.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no Java equivalent of C# Linq

Comment: Java has `Stream` compared to C# LINQ, but not exact equivalent. Usually the stream used in lambda e.g. `lst.stream().filter(f -> f.getDataChangedTime()).someOtherMethod().collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: @Rango Thank you  Rango

Comment: You could have a look at `java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>)` from Java's Streams API. See docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C#-code is already explained by @Rango. Assuming the following design for the `Log`-class in C#

```
class Log
{
    public String title;
    public String ID;
    public DateTime dataChangeTime;
    public String whatever;
    ...
}
```

and an analogous Java-class (with e.g. `LocalDateTime` instead of `DateTime`), a Java-expression providing the same result is:

```
Comparator<Log> comparator = (Log l1, Log l2) -> l2.dataChangeTime.compareTo(l1.dataChangeTime);    // sort descending
List<Log> resultantList = initialList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.title + l.ID)).values().stream()                          // group according to title and id
    .map(logs -> logs.stream().sorted(comparator).findFirst().get())                                // sort and take the first
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                                                                  // create the list
```

The expression groups all `Log`-objects together having the same title and ID, i.e. the same value of `l.title + l.ID`. If the grouping-condition is more complex then it might make more sense to define a class which represents the grouping, e.g.

```
class LogGroup {

    private String Title;
    private String ID;

    public LogGroup(String Title, String ID) {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LogGroup)) {
            return false;
        }
        LogGroup logGroup = (LogGroup) o;
        return Objects.equals(Title, logGroup.Title) &&
               Objects.equals(ID, logGroup.ID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(Title, ID);
    }
}
```

It's crucial that the class implements both, the `equals`- and the `hashCode`-method (i.e the implementation of the `equals`-method alone is not enough).

Using that class the Java-expression becomes:

```
Comparator<Log> comparator = (Log l1, Log l2) -> l2.dataChangeTime.compareTo(l1.dataChangeTime);
List<Log> resultantList = initialList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> new LogGroup(l.title, l.ID))).values().stream()
    .map(logs -> logs.stream().sorted(comparator).findFirst().get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A list like

```
private static List<Log> getInitialList() {
    List<Log> initialList = new ArrayList<>();
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 6", "ID 6", LocalDateTime.of(2017,  1, 18, 23, 15, 12), "A"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 3", "ID 3", LocalDateTime.of(2005,  4, 20, 16, 10, 10), "B"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 1", "ID 1", LocalDateTime.of(2010, 10, 25,  3,  5,  2), "C"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 2", "ID 2", LocalDateTime.of(2018,  2, 18, 21, 13, 32), "D"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 3", "ID 3", LocalDateTime.of(2016,  5, 16, 15, 23, 15), "E"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 1", "ID 1", LocalDateTime.of(2012,  2,  8, 14, 46, 28), "F"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 6", "ID 6", LocalDateTime.of(1996,  1, 28, 22, 26, 34), "G"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 3", "ID 3", LocalDateTime.of(2007,  4, 15,  2,  5, 55), "H"));
    initialList.add(new Log("Title 6", "ID 3", LocalDateTime.of(2018,  1, 15, 20, 15, 10), "I"));
   return initialList;
}
```

is processed by both expressions as follows

```
Title 1    ID 1    2012-02-08 14:46:28    F
Title 3    ID 3    2016-05-16 15:23:15    E
Title 2    ID 2    2018-02-18 21:13:32    D
Title 6    ID 6    2017-01-18 23:15:12    A
Title 6    ID 3    2018-01-15 20:15:10    I
```

The resultant list itself isn't sorted (which would be easy to implement with `Collections.sort(...)`), but that applies also to the C#-output.